# Any objections to adding a [sophie-germain] tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tags

I have just started reading about the life, work, anonymity and discrimination towards the French  mathematician, physicist, and philosopher [Sophie Germain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain). I've added it to [my new question](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/14395/3869) and three others, for a grand total of four questions so far.

I don't know how to view a constellation of tags for individuals in order to judge how well this one this one fits, but to me the combination of her contributions mathematics and physics, interactions Carl Friedrich Gauss and other contemporary mathematician, and her own story seems to be of sufficient saliency to warrant a tag.

> Because of prejudice against her sex, she was unable to make a career out of mathematics, but she worked independently throughout her life. **Before her death, Gauss had recommended that she be awarded an honorary degree, but that never occurred.** On 27 June 1831, she died from breast cancer. At the centenary of her life, a street and a girls’ school were named after her. **The Academy of Sciences established the Sophie Germain Prize in her honor.**

**Question:** Any objections to adding a [sophie-germain](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sophie-germain) tag?

---

Potentially related:

- [Are questions about mathematicians and scientists' lives on topic?](https://hsm.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1/3869)
- [Tagging of names, revisited](https://hsm.meta.stackexchange.com/q/285/3869)
- [Tagging of names](https://hsm.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3/3869)